# Page redirection without hash part

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

I have following get route in expressjs `app.js` file.

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) { 
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('/admin/login');

},Routes.Admin.Index);
```

If the user is not logged in (not authenticated) and has accessed to the route `/admin#/dashboard` above implementation redirects the user to `/admin/login#/dashboard` , but how could I redirect the user to `/admin/login` only; not to `/admin/login#/dashboard`? The `#/dashboard` part is completely unnecessary for `/admin/login` so it should not be there for at least when my `server` redirects. I would not care it if the user manually enters it in the address bar for `/admin/login/` route.

**UPDATE**

These two things

```
<a href="/admin/login"> Login </a>

window.location.href = "/admin/login";
```

doesnot care what is currently in addressbar , but why

```
res.redirect('/admin/login')
```

does?

Comment: You mean `/admin/login#dashboard` ? `/admin/login/#/dashboard` would be a different route.

Comment: Yes, I mean `/admin/login#dashboard`. I will edit my question if they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL hash is not sent to the server. Hence the server cannot change it in the redirect. If you want to change the hash part, then send the following script to the client, and from the client side do a redirect.

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) { 
    return next();
  }

  res.send('<html><body><script>window.location.href="/admin/login";</script>');

},Routes.Admin.Index);
```

UPDATE : Lets say I enter /admin#dashboard in the location bar. The request that goes to the server is for /admin only. When you do a redirect from the server to /admin/login, when the response comes back, the browser will only replace /admin to /admin/login. The hash part remains unchanged.